# How to load variables from a text file (.env) for a single process without exporting the variables?

Tags: environment-variables

> Note: This general topic seems to be covered ad nauseum on more than one SE site, but please read through all the details — I don't find any questions which cover all the criteria described below.
>
> Also: I'm using `zsh` in the examples below. I'm hoping for a POSIX-compliant solution, but that's not a hard requirement: something that works for `bash` and `zsh` is good enough.

Here's an example to help clarify the question title:

Let's say I have the following two files:

```txt
% ls -AF
.env    printenv*

% cat printenv
echo $LOCAL_MESSAGE_1
echo $LOCAL_MESSAGE_2

% cat .env
LOCAL_MESSAGE_1="hello world"
LOCAL_MESSAGE_2="goodnight moon"
```

and I'd like to execute the script `printenv` and see the following in `stdout`:

```txt
hello world
goodnight moon
```

If those variables don't exist in my environment, the script prints empty lines (as expected):

```txt
% unset LOCAL_MESSAGE_1

% unset LOCAL_MESSAGE_2

% ./printenv
```

If I set the variables before executing the script, they become available to it, but only for that single process, and not to any subsequent processes launched from the same shell:

```txt
% LOCAL_MESSAGE_1="hello world" LOCAL_MESSAGE_2="goodnight moon" ./printenv
hello world
goodnight moon

% ./printenv
```

So, my question is this: How can I replicate the behavior in the last example according to the following criteria?

1. run `printenv` without modification in the current shell — not in a subshell (thanks [RudiC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/727361/1)) — and get the desired output, while also
2. loading the variables from the `.env` file, while also
3. keeping the variables local to that process invocation: they will remain unset in the shell environment and to subsequent processes **without needing to `unset` them**

What single line syntax can I use to accomplish this? What should be substituted in place of the question marks below to meet the criteria above?

```txt
% ?????????? ./printenv
hello world
goodnight moon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to run those in a subshell (in `bash`)? Like

```
( . .env; . ./printenv )
hello world
goodnight moon
```

That way, the LOCAL variables are set for the `printenv` script only, and the parent shell's environment remains unchanged.

With your new, extended requirements (no subshell), try an approach using the (unwelcome, dangerous) `eval` :

```
eval $(< .env) ./printenv
hello world
goodnight moon
```

It puts the variables' definition and the command in one line, then `eval`s and executes that line.

Comment: This is good, and made me realize that I failed to define a criterion, which is that the process itself needs to run in the current shell. I'll update the question to include that. Sorry about that — and thanks!

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to source the variables text file in a subshell and then print/interpolate them into a string that is then evaluated inline in the parent shell before invoking the script — like in the example command that manually sets them prior to execution (`$ var1=val1 var2=val2 ./script`)?

Comment: You can't convey back variables / values from sub to parent. Look at my second approach in my extended answer.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the dangers of unsanitized string evaluation, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain a bit more — or better — link me to documentation about how the [`<` operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283374/what-does-the-left-chevron-triangle-bracket-do) works here when used with [command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/442704/46524) and `eval`?

Comment: `man bash`: "... The  command  substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file)."

Answer (score 0):

With [`runenv`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runenv.8) (which is part of a package called [perp](http://b0llix.net/perp/) - aka the perpetrator):

```
runenv env_file command
```

will
*"run `command` without modification in the current shell — not in a subshell  — and get the desired output, while also loading the variables from the `env_file`, while also keeping the variables local to that process invocation: they will remain unset in the shell environment and to subsequent processes without needing to unset them"*

Answer (score -1):

You can source your scripts to your shell using ". script" syntax:

. .env && . ./printenv

You can also add the ". .env" to the beginning of your printenv script. Then you will be able to exec printenv as:

./printenv

'printenv' is not good name choice because it is used by shell.

Comment: This approach sets the LOCAL_MESSAGE variables which is undesired.

Comment: @jonasmike [This comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/727357/how-to-load-variables-from-a-text-file-env-for-a-single-process-without-expor/727361#comment1378951_727360) is accurate. Also: "_'printenv' is not good name choice because it is used by shell_": of course, you're right: it's not a good idea to shadow process names that are commonly available — that was just the first name that came to mind in the context of my question, so I went with it. Thanks for pointing out good practices!