# Load variables with source with a single line scope

Tags: bash, environment-variables, source

In bash and other shells, I can make same variables have "line scope" by defining it just before a command.

```
CXX=clang++ ./script.bash
```

Which I prefer over

```
export CXX=clang++
./script.bash
```

because the former doesn't contaminate the environment.

**How can I do the same with variables set by `source` and achieve the same "line scope" effect?**

The equivalent of:

```
source env.source  # defines a bunch of vars
./script.bash
```

```
??? ./script.bash
```

Comment: same or almost the same as here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/727357

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sub-shell:

```bash
( source env.source && ./script.bash )
```

The environment inside the sub-shell is destroyed when the sub-shell terminates.

Or, in `bash`, set `BASH_ENV` for the script:

```bash
BASH_ENV=./env.source ./script.bash
```

The `BASH_ENV` variable comes into effect for non-interactive shells (i.e. scripts). If the variable is set to the pathname of a dot-script, that dot-script will be sourced before the body of the main script runs. Note that the dot-script will not be searched for in `$PATH` when using `BASH_ENV`, which is different from when using `.` or `source`, so you need to provide the complete path (relative or absolute).

("dot-script" == a script that is sourced with the `.` (dot) utility, which is also known as `source` in `bash`.)